# "the moment [where/when] he has been waiting for"

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, wh-questions

Which is correct?

> This is the moment where he has been waiting for

or

> This is the moment when he has been waiting for

Can someone please explain

Comment: Neither. It's *This is the moment **that** he has been waiting for*. But note [that] the "relativiser" ***that*** (or ***which***) is optional in such contexts.

Answer (score 2):

A moment is not a place, so it cannot be ***where***.

Now, a moment can be a place in time, so ***when*** would seem to be obvious. You could use it about a moment in other sentences, like:

> That's the moment when you'll realise what really matters to you.

However, in this case, it's just not used. The idiomatic sentence would be:

> This is the moment **that** he has been waiting for.

However, there's no need for any preposition. It's optional. You could just say:

> This is moment he has been waiting for.